# Joblib crashes with an unexplainable error, what could cause it?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

[Joblib](http://pythonhosted.org/joblib/) crashes on the Parallel call line and this is the two last traces in the stack trace (other lines are just the call to Parallel and Main):

```
  File "/home/zed/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 519, in __call__
    self.retrieve()
  File "/home/zed/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 450, in retrieve
    raise exception_type(report)
TypeError: function takes exactly 5 arguments (1 given)
```

This happens after a while, the function that is being 'delayed' does indeed require 5 arguments and they are all supplied, since several jobs are executed successfully...

What could cause this/ how to debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What could cause this/ how to debug this?

If you can reproduce the error in sequential mode (setting the number of concurrent jobs `n_jobs` to `1`) then the traceback might be more informative.